# Mongodb Query Multiple Levels Deep

Tags: database, mongodb, python-2.7, nosql, pymongo

I have the following document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a202aa0728bac010a8d2467"), 
    "tickers" : {
        "information_technology" : [
            "ACN", 
            "ATVI", 
            "ADBE", 
            "AMD", 
        ],
       "misc" : [
            "AA", 
            "GE", 
            "AAPL", 
            "PFE", 
        ] 
    }, 
    "name" : "S&P500"
}
```

I want to query the document by name ("S&P500") and return a list within the "tickers" field.

I tried db.collection.find_one("$and": [{'name': 'S&P500'}, {'tickers': 'misc'}]) but no documents were returned.

I am new to mongodb so I may have missed something in the documentation.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The API for `Collection.find_one` is similar with `Collection.find` **except that `limit` is ignored** and a single document returned for a match or `None` if there is no match.

> find(filter=None, projection=None, skip=0, limit=0, no_cursor_timeout=False, cursor_type=CursorType.NON_TAILABLE, sort=None, allow_partial_results=False, oplog_replay=False, modifiers=None, manipulate=True) [Docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)

An appropriate filter is `{'name': 'S&P500'}` when looking to match documents with `name` equals `S&P500`.

Also, an appropriate projection is `{'tickers.misc': True}` when projecting only `tickers.misc`.

```
db.collection.find_one({'name': 'S&P500'}, {'tickers.misc': True})
```